# Virtualbox freezes desktop in Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: virtualbox, freeze

So I've had this Ubuntu 22.10 install on this laptop for a little bit and decided to try out arch linux in virtualbox. For some reason, after a little while of trying to get it set up, the entire desktop freezes and I am forced to reboot the system using a TTY console.

Is this an issue with Ubuntu 22.10, or Ubuntu in general? Should I downgrade to 22.04 LTS?

[image]
[image: Arch VM]

Comment: Is there anything in the system log that might point to the cause of the problem? Which version of VirtualBox is installed? The team at Oracle tend to put out one dud every three releases, which can cause all sorts of issues on the host system … 

Comment: From what I see it doesn't look like it in the logs. I'm using Virtualbox 7.0.2

Comment: I would certainly reduce the number of cores assigned to the VM. You have a 5 years old Quad-core processor that thanks to hyper-treading (and hyper-threading alone) can "simulate" 8 cores. It doesn't mean that you can assign 4 cores to a VM with impunity.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you ^^